# CE 1.9 - Create order in Backend and ask customer to pay for it on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-methods, backend

Is it possible to create an order on behalf of a customer from the backend, save it so that an order number is generated, and then somehow get/guide the customer to pay for it on the frontend?

I imagine something where the order will be created with the Order Status set to *Pending Payment*, and then the customer will either be asked to log in to access their cart with items pre-populated from where they can then checkout, or they will need to punch in some unique reference (perhaps under the Orders Information form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an order and then ask the customer to pay for it is not possible without creating a custom payment method along with the workflow that would enable the customer to login, select there order, and enter there credit card info.

However by default magento allow you to create a quote in the admin (not an order) and move it to the customer cart.

[image]

Comment: Hey RS! Thanks.  Let me have a closer look at that and I'll get back to you. The catch here is that we are using ID'S Sales Rep Tracking extension, so we need to know which backend user created the order ... which means it would need to be either placed or saved.

Comment: It's hard to advice without knowing the internal workflow, but you could create an order place  observer (for register customer or by email) and look up if there is a sales rep associate with this customer. Also some module will display a field at checkout for the customer to select there sales rep

Comment: Yes this extension does give that option on the frontend to select a sales rep. I'm starting now with my investigation so I'll let you know how it goes